# AngularJS upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5 routes not loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I upgraded our AngularJS package from 1.4.14 to 1.5.11. In doing so, our routes unexpectedly stopped loading. The base url for our application is baseurl.com/app.

I've reviewed the angularjs migration documents, but cannot find anything that has helped me to fix this issue.

```js
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the top level
    .when('/', {
        template : '<home></home>',
    })

    // route for a new project
    .when('/new', {
        template : '<new></new>',
    })

    // route for the project overview page
    .when('/view', {
        template : '<overview></overview>',
    })

    // route for the manage page
    .when('/manage', {
        template : '<manage></manage>',
    })

    // route for the base perform page
    .when('/perform', {
        template : '<perform></perform>',
    })

    // default route
    .otherwise('/');
    });
```

Comment: do the `angular.js` and `angular-route.js` versions match?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yes, they are both setup to use 1.5.11

Comment: How do you use your routing? With buttons? Do you have a hash-bang in URL? `#!/` or `#/`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey we do use buttons for routing. However, I cannot get the initial homepage to load. I've also read about the hash-bang additions to urls, but that didn't help to fix the initial page load either.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I've also noticed that if I use baseurl.com/app# in the browser the page loads fine.

Comment: that is the hash-bang, that you supposed to have. You are telling me you didn't have it before? Were you using `html5mode`, or something? Redirect to `baseurl.com/app#/view` to test if it works

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, correct we didn't have that before. I believe angular automatically added the hash on page load in version 1.4.11. We have not used html5Mode either, but I've read up on that as well.

Comment: yeah, you can completely remove the hash from your URL, but you need to fix the routing manually on [server-side](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side). It's simpler to just leave it

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, ok I'll look into routing on the server-side. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the code below

```
.run(['$route', function() {}]);
```

This was a known issue in the AngularJS documentation that I missed somehow.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ngRoute#known-issues